# Need github repo commit list without based upon user

Tags: github-api

Im trying to get the commit list from GitHub repo using its API.
I am getting the commit list but its based upon particular user.

I need the list based upon the commit happened.

Below is the url I am using:

https://api.github.com/repos/user_name_here/repo_name_here/commits?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX&per_page=5

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the commits returns by the API will list *all* the commits from a particular repo, for *all* authors (ie not based on a user).

See for instance the [commits of GitLabhq repo](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commits/master):

https://api.github.com/repos/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commits

You will get all commits, without restriction. You will get both the original author and committer name as well.